# How to solidify curve projected onto mesh with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to use geometry nodes to setup a curve that will control an extrusion on my shoe like below:

[image]

Currently the best way I've found to project the curve onto the mesh is via a raycast node but when it comes to creating the Solidify I'm unsure of how to fill in the result so that it is not a pipe? And that it will follow the shoe along the shape rather than go back to the original curve (See 2nd image)

Has anyone tried something similar or could recommend a better way for splitting apart the meshes to get 2 clean separate mesh islands?

[image]

[image]

Comment: since you're raycasting the curve from a starting 2D form, you can use "fill curve" first (which works only for 2D curves), then raycast, then solidify. You're up for some topology problems, so after filling curve, you might want to subdivide it heavily…

Comment: Thanks that has given me a decent result, as you said topology isn't the greatest but subdividing the curve does help a lot! I'm still getting ugly clipping happening on the resulting solidify for the part of the curve that is outside the toe, any thoughts on how to fix that? maybe if there's a way to boolean the curve before I raycast it?
Thanks again for your help